# scale column width with image width

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm writing a presentation using the `beamer` class where multiple slides consist of an `image` on the very right and centered text on the left.

So far I do this using the `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    centered text\\spanning multiple lines
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-golden-upright}
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I have to set the column widths manually to make the right column have the same width as the image.

[image: golden ratio slide]

As you can see, there is a some white space left right to the image.

How can I make the right column as wide as the image and the left one occupy the remaining space?

If you have a solution without using `colums` that would also be fine (as long as the image is rightmost and the text centers in the free space left to it).

I need this automated since I have that multiple times using many pictures with different aspect-ratios. So the column widths need to be different on each slide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You *can* add images; use the interface and remove the `!` in front of the link. A user with suitable privileges will reinsert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear if you want to use overlays; if you don't, here's the definition of an environment that does the necessary computations. I add also a “less automatized” solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\newsavebox{\mycolwidthbox}
%% Better way
\newenvironment{picturecolumn}[2][]
 {\sbox\mycolwidthbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\mycolwidth}{\wd\mycolwidthbox}%
  \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mycolwidth}
  \centering}
 {\end{column}
  \begin{column}{\mycolwidth}
  \usebox{\mycolwidthbox}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}}

%% Simpler way
\newcommand{\setmycolwidth}[2][]{%
  \settowidth{\mycolwidth}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{picturecolumn}[height=\dimexpr\paperheight-5pt]{example-image-golden-upright}
\centering
centered text\\
spanning multiple lines
\end{picturecolumn}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\setmycolwidth[height=\paperheight]{example-image-golden-upright}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mycolwidth}
\centering
centered text\\
spanning multiple lines
\end{column}
\begin{column}{\mycolwidth}
\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-golden-upright}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not going to use overlays, so this solution worked perfectly for me. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood that right, that you want to get rid of the space right to the image, here is a solution involving parboxes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{geometry} will be loaded with beamer
\newlength\rightcolumn
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt,includeall}
 \begin{frame}[plain]
 \settowidth{\rightcolumn}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-golden-upright}}
   \parbox[t][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth-\rightcolumn}{%
    \centering%
    centered text\\spanning multiple lines
   }%
   \parbox[t][\paperheight][c]{\rightcolumn}{%
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-golden-upright}
   }%
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this results in:
[image]

Comment: This seems to work, too. Is there any improvement by using parboxes instead of columns? If so, I guess I could adjust egregs environment definition to use parboxes.

Comment: I like using parboxes, makes me feel having everything under control. There is not more improvement over using columns, but as parboxes are a very lowlevel command you cannot go wrong in making things messi in other environments. I usually find it much simpler writing code for a parbox than adapting an environment. But that is just flavour.